# How did they get the following vector regarding tangent planes?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I get that the (0,1,1) vector is perpendicular to the gradient of the function but what about the one circled in red? Also how did they get 2λx_0 ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is, at least for some people, a slight difference between the tangent plane at some point and a plane that is tangent to the surface as some point. It seems the cited text uses both variants without distinction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $l:=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3: \exists t \in \mathbb{R}, (x,y,z)=(1,2,0)+t(0,1,1)\} $ $M_0\in l$ and $P:=(1,2,0) \in l$. So, $\vec{PM_0} =M_0-P$ is a direction vector of $l$, with $M_0-P=(x_0-1,y_0-2,z_0)$. So, $u:=(z_0-y_0+2,x_0-1,-x_0+1)$ is another normal direction(as explained). As $\nabla F=(2x_0,2y_0,-2z_0)$ is. So, $\exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R}: u=\lambda \nabla F$, i.e. $(z_0-y_0+2,x_0-1,-x_0+1)=\lambda (2x_0,2y_0,-2z_0)$.

Answer (score 0):

The affine plane that is tangent to the surface in some point $X_0=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is given as
$$
\langle \nabla F,\,X-X_0\rangle=0
$$
The line can be parametrized as $P+sV$ with $P=(1,2,0)$ and $V=(0,1,1)$. That the line lies in the plane means that
$$
0=⟨∇F,P+sV−X_0⟩=⟨∇F,P−X_0⟩+s⟨∇F,V⟩
$$
For a scalar linear function to be zero everywhere means that its coefficients have to be zero. In consequence
$$
0=y_0-z_0 \\
0=x_0(1-x_0)+y_0(2-y_0)-z_0(0-z_0)=x_0+2y_0-1
$$
Now we have to find where the line $(1-2t,t,t)$ intersects the surface
$$
1=(1-2t)^2+t^2-t^2\iff t=0\lor t=1
$$
so that $X=(1,0,0)$ or $X=(-1,1,1)$.